# sed: Deleting a List of Paths from a Set of Files

Tags: linux, bash, sed, text-editing

I have a file named **common.txt** that contains a list of absolute paths. For example:

```
/etc
/etc/group
/var/log/syslog
```

I also have a set of files **<hostname>.txt** that also contain a list of absolute paths. Here is an example (call it **host1.txt**):

```
/root/.bashrc
/var/log/syslog
/etc/hosts
/bin/true
/etc
/sbin/rtmon
/etc/group
```

I would like to remove every path that appears in **common.txt** from every file in the set of files **<filename>.txt**. So, the example file **host1.txt** above would become:

```
/root/.bashrc
/etc/hosts
/bin/true
/sbin/rtmon
```

I have written the following Bash script to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o nounset
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail

while read -r ONE_PATH
do
   for ONE_FILE in host1.txt host2.txt host3.txt
   do
      sed -i '\:'"$ONE_PATH"':d' "$ONE_FILE"
   done
done < common.txt
```

I am having a difficult time getting the sed command right. What's shown above results in all files operated upon becoming empty.

How may I fix this so as to accomplish my goal?

Comment: The output of `grep -v -f common.txt somefile.txt` is  the contents of `somefile.txt` without any lines that contains a line in `common.txt`.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of both files and the result you'd like to see?  Just so that I can test my answer.

Comment: I have provided the requested example to enhance the thread for future readers, but I have not yet had a chance to try your revised solution.

Comment: What is the output of `sed '\:^/etc$:d' host1.txt`? If any. Dave's answer below has a point. `common.txt` has `/etc`, because of that the line `/etc/hosts` will be deleted from host1.txt as well,  `sed` will delete ALL lines that contain `/etc` according to your address. Add anchors to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o nounset
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail

declare -r SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
declare -r FILES_DIR=${SCRIPT_DIR%/*}

while read -r ONE_PATH
do
   for ONE_FILE in $(find "$FILES_DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print)
   do
      if [[ "$ONE_FILE" == *".swp" ]] ||
         [[ "$ONE_FILE" == *"common.txt" ]]; then
         continue
      fi

      sed -i '\|^'"$ONE_PATH"'$|d' "$ONE_FILE"
   done

echo "Done removing $ONE_PATH"
done < "$SCRIPT_DIR"/../common.txt

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a solution that doesn't use sed?

```
sort common.txt > common.txt.sorted
for f in host1.txt host2.txt host3.txt ; do
    sort $f > $f.sorted
    diff common.txt.sorted $f.sorted | egrep '^>' | sed -e 's/^> //' > $f.output
    rm $f.sorted
done
```

**sort** sorts lists in alphabetical order.  **diff** finds the differences between the a file and **common.txt**. **egrep** picks out lines that start with `>`, which are lines in **host1.txt.sorted** but not in **common.txt.sorted**.  Finally, **sed** removes the leading `>` (that's > followed by a space) added by **diff**.

The output list will be in alphabetical order too.

Answer (score -1):

First the input should be sorted in reverse.  It's no use removing /etc and then go looking for /etc/group. Then we verify if the file can be written to (if not skip). Then ONE_PATH should be escaped and then sed can do its work,

```
sort -r common.txt \
| while read -r ONE_PATH
do
   for ONE_FILE in host1.txt host2.txt host3.txt
   do
      if [ -w "$ONE_FILE" ]
      then
        # sed -i '\:'"$ONE_PATH"':d' "$ONE_FILE"
        ONE_PATH_ESC=$(echo "$ONE_PATH" | sed "s!/!\\\/!g")
        sed -i 's/^'"$ONE_PATH_ESC"'//' "$ONE_FILE"
      fi
   done
done
```

With the test data provided, you get:

```
$ pr -n host1.txt
1   /root/.bashrc
2
3   /hosts
4   /bin/true
5
6   /sbin/rtmon
7
```

There are 3 empty lines.

Comment: You haven't tested this, have you?

Comment: @Scott Now I have.